# shell script using sed to count number of lines skipping header and trailer records (n-2 lines of a file)

Tags: bash, shell, file, sed

I am able to get the total no of lines in a file and was able to append the `date|count`  record at the end of the file but the file has the header and the trailer record and I should get the count excluding those two lines.

My Code:

```
daatee="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
NumLines="$(sed -n '$=' test.txt)"
sed -i "$ a $daatee|$NumLines" test.txt
```

Current Output:
`20180925|10`

Expected Output:
`20180925|8`

Experts please help me fix my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
printf "%s|%s\n" "$(date "+%Y%m%d")" $(($(wc -l < test.txt) - 2)) >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.